# Process/Flow/steps for speeding of the booting time in raspberry pi for the cluster

Tags: boot, bluetooth, gui, qt, buildroot

I am using Raspberry pi for the cluster, that would display the basic data like the CAN data and one wire data.
For can I used the Can-Socket and for one wire I am just reading a gpio pin of raspberry pi.
Also for navigation I am screencasting using vnc.
OS used- Raspbian bullseye legacy 32 bit
for the UI it is run using the Midori software.

The booting time is nearly 20seconds. which i probably need in 3-4 seconds.

As I see videos on cluster i see is - using buildroot, using qt/qml for UI.
For navigation I see is they have built an mobile application and navigating through bluetooth

I want to know the approach and understand the way that should be followed.
I am certainly not getting any tutorial explaining this.

Comment: You might want to clarify what it is you actually need to have happen within 3-4 seconds, since "booting time" is very ambiguous: Do you mean: 1) The time it takes to load the kernel and start the init system? 2) The time before a login prompt is available? 3) The time it takes for a GUI application or desktop to load?  4) The time it takes for a specific background service to start? 5) The time it takes to connect to a network?  Etc. -- see also the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).

Comment: the time it takes for the GUI application to load..

Comment: What does a "cluster" mean - there is no detail of what hardware you are using.

Comment: i am receiving data from can and one wire from a separate controller. I want to show those data on a dashboard. i did achieve this but the booting time to a full interactive gui takes about 20seconds. I want to achieve the same within 3-4 seconds. what should I  probably do. like building a custom os